# What is this type of consistency called in DataRetrieval?

Tags: database-theory

I am trying to find the name of this feature that is implemented with SQL Databases:

Given a Record $R^1$ in table having two values for two different fields, e.g. 
Let value of field 1 $F_1$ be $V_1$, Let value of field 2 $F_2$ be $V_2$
A any query requiring records s.t. $F_1 = V_1$ should contain $R^1$.
Also any query requiring records s.t. $F_2 = V_2$ should also contain $R^1$.

If a database does not have the above property then it definitely considered broken.

My question is what is the name for this kind of consistency?

Comment: I don't think this is consistency. It's just specification of the operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call it expected consistency.

Unless you are just defining the $=$ operator.

When you get into transactions can have uncommitted or dirty value. By default $=$ will only match committed values but you can search on the uncommitted value. Look up [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) around data consistency.

Also careful with *any* as with an AND condition it needs to satisfy both so you may not get $R^1$ for $F_2 = V_2$ if another AND condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Your question's context is somewhat underspecified. Is there any form of distribution or concurrency going on?

In the absence of more context, I am assuming the most general context so I'd say this is strict consistency, the strongest form of consistency.